# sed bash - replace only one character between match pattern

Tags: linux, bash, sed, replace

I have a file with the next information:

```
[1,1,h][1,2,o][1,3,l][1,4,a][1,5, ][1,6,c][1,7,o][1,8,m][1,9,o][2,0,
][2,1,e][2,2,s][2,3,t][2,4,a][2,5,i][2,6,s][1,7,y][1,8,o]
```

I would like to replace for example `[1,8,m]` with new value for example `[1,8,k]` and move all the next information until return char `[2,0, ]`. The return char is the space but really the information need to be like that:

```
[1,1,h][1,2,o][1,3,l][1,4,a][1,5, ][1,6,c][1,7,o][1,8,k][1,9,m][1,10,o][2,0,
][2,1,e][2,2,s][2,3,t][2,4,a][2,5,i][2,6,s][2,7,y][2,8,o]
```

1 and 8 are storage in variables. I don't know  If i can to move all information until `[2,0, ]` with sed, but is not possible, I will prepare a function. The basical is change `[1,8,m]` for `[1,8,k]` and save before `m` for latter replace all the character.

Comment: Can you describe the change? Why is there `[1,9,m][1,10.o]` instead of `[1,9,o]`? Why where the 1s changed to 2s at the end of the second line/

Comment: Do you REALLY have a newline in the middle of `[2,0,
]`? If not, please [edit] your question to fix that.

Comment: There are many more differences between your input and output.  Is there a logic to that?  You could do a "brute force" series of sed replacements for each `[X,Y,Z]' block you want to replace.  The segment of your question I do not understand is *and save before m for latter replace all the character.*

Comment: The challenge is that the last  character replaced need to go to the next triplet....and in sequence until [2,0, ]. Really i m try to do a editor in pure bash. When insert a character i need to move all the next character  occurrence until next line . The next line is represented by the 2 number [2, 0, ] where 2 is the next line and 0 the column . Dont worry about input and output . This is correct controller in another function and if i insert o deleted characters automatically the [line , col,character] is inserted in the file. Maybe later I will put in array.